# Get list of potential queries from Navigator pane

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

Not overly elegant but here is a solution to get the potential queries:

```
qString1 =  'let Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents('+'"'+_app.session.oRep.outputfilename+'"'+'), [Implementation='+'"'+"1.3"+'"'+']), ;
            TransposeSource = Table.Transpose(Source), ;
            SourceHeaderPromoted = Table.PromoteHeaders(TransposeSource, [PromoteAllScalars=true]), ;
            initquerylist = Table.ColumnNames(SourceHeaderPromoted), ;
```

Comment: I don't quite follow. Can you clarify your input and expected output and include the M code you are working with?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. A PDF document that exhibits the problem, and a clear explanation, might be helpful. Or perhaps `#sections` which will return a record containing all of the queries in the current environment?

Comment: There is no problem with the pdf and powerquery is working appropriately.  The list of queries I am trying to get would be the equivalent to the UI that allows you to pick the queries to transform and import.  PDF.Tables should return a table with all the tables that powerquery found.  I am trying to get that list with Table.ToList but powerquery isn't recognizing Source.  The initquerylist step I don't think is working.

Comment: Your problem remains unclear.  But if, as you write, what you want is: "the number of queries initially created from the pdf.", you can, with a fresh document (i.e. no other queries), set up the connection to PQ and check the tables you want to import. Then, in your PQ code, use the `#sections` keyword and compute a count of the number of records.  If there are unrelated queries, you will need to filter them out before computing the count.  You can do this within your PDF query, or as a separate function.